# React Hooks for setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to figure out how to use Hooks to display the number that a slider is at. This number should change as the slider moves. I had this working without hooks, but now I'm trying to make it work with them as I think it's important to learn. I feel like I'm close to solving this, but there's just some knowledge that I don't have that I need to make it work. Have any advice or help? Thanks! I left my previous code attached commented out so you can see how it worked. My code below:

JS(Babel):

```
Slider = () => {
// function Slider() {

  const [value, setValue] = useState(120.5);
  // state = { value: 120.5 };

  useEffect(() => {})
  // onUpdate(e) {
  //   this.setState({
  //     value: e.target.value
  //   });
  // }  

  return (
    <div className="slider-box">
      <div>
        <label className="slider-label">{value}c</label>
        <p className="slider-title">Scale</p>
      </div>
      <StyledSlider
        list="tickmarks"
        max={1200}
        onChange={() => setValue(value + 1)}
        step={0.01}
        type="range"
        value={value} //{this.state.value}
      />
      <div> 
        <p className="slider-scale">1200 x 1200</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Whats happening if you click on the slider? Does the value change or not? If the StyledSlider is a custom component that has onChange event on it you just need to pass the "setValue" and call it inside the StyledSlider

Comment: i don't see something wrong here in the code

Comment: There is an error that comes up, I cannot see the slider. The error is: Line 14:29:   'useState' is not defined   no-undef
  Line 17:3:    'useEffect' is not defined  no-undef

Comment: Import them then. As any other things in JS, they won't come out of nowhere.

Comment: `import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';` in this way, you could import.

Comment: Estus Flask- love the username Skeleton! I thought I had imported them. Sorry, I'm very new to this. What do you mean?

Comment: As it was suggested above. And naturally they are available as React.useState,etc

Comment: Okay! Thats what you meant! Thank you @softengineer123 I didn't know I had to do that. Yor now I can answer your question, when I click on the slider, nothing changes.

Comment: Huh. I tinkered around a bit and it's working now, but very very slowly. It wont follow your curser properly. You have to drag it across the screen to get a few decimals.

Comment: Think you could create a *running* codesandbox that reproduces your issue? It's also a bit unclear to me why the slider input is controlled (via `value` prop) but you don't consume the updated slider value in the `onChange` handler. Your `step` is `0.01` but you only increment `value` by `1` on each change, so I'm not surprised it doesn't track the handle drag. Can you update your question to also include the `StyledSlider` component?

Comment: @DrewReese exactly. I believe all that needs changing is to use the actual event to change the state

Comment: You all are exactly right. I did what you suggested @DrewReese and its working properly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that using the same logic you were before. There is no reason to increment your state one by one, just use the value you get from the event like you were doing previously in your `onUpdate` handler.

```
Slider = () => {
// function Slider() {

  const [value, setValue] = useState(120.5);
  // state = { value: 120.5 };


  const onUpdate = (e) => {
     setValue(e.target.value);

   }  

  return (
    <div className="slider-box">
      <div>
        <label className="slider-label">{value}c</label>
        <p className="slider-title">Scale</p>
      </div>
      <StyledSlider
        list="tickmarks"
        max={1200}
        onChange={onUpdate}
        step={0.01}
        type="range"
        value={value} //{this.state.value}
      />
      <div> 
        <p className="slider-scale">1200 x 1200</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```